# Access to debug variables in a Eclipse CDT plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I want to create an Eclipse plugin which can get access to the same data that is presented in the variables view when debugging a C/C++ application. For example I want to create a view that can present variables from the debugger in different ways.

I have looked in the CDT Developer guide but couldn't find anything about this.

First I thought I could create a `SelectionListener` and extract the data I want when the user clicks on a variable in the `VariableView` but I get an instance of `GdbVariableVMNode` which is internal and not useful. Can I adapt this into something?

Am I supposed to use the `CDebugCorePlugin` or is there another interface into CDT debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself. I can use the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.memoryRenderings` extension point. It lets me provide a class implementing `IMemoryRendering`, the init method will provide me with an instance of a `IMemoryBlock` from which I can get the actual values from debugged variables.